If all are eternally and simultaneously liberated is this against to bramhan or any personal dieties
All are liberated means all experience all Karmas and rebirths knowingly consciously in a liberated manner until they attain final liberation by completely merging into God Brahman if this happens permanently across all infinite cycles of creation preservation and destruction is this against to bramhan or any personal dieties that means all are partially liberated in every birth and experience all Karmas and rebirths in awareness manner that this is a divine drama but they want all karmas and rebirths as a part of divine play until their final birth where they attain final liberation by completely merging into Brahmhan
